# get fcm can't token in syria without proxy

Tags: android, cordova

Is there anyway i can get token from firebase cloud messaging without using proxy in a county banned from use google service like syria?

I'm using cordova-plugin-firebase like this.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
    // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
    console.log(token);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```